# Pyro CMS : Creating a REST Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, pyrocms

I am a complete nob in Codeigniter so please ignore if m being stupid.
I have played with pyro cms for a while and i would like to have an API which could 
return all the blogs in JSOn / XML format. 
I have created a controller in the path :-
pyrocms-pyrocms-dc143bc/system/cms/controllers/api(Created this folder)/mobile.php
Following is the code :-

```
  <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
   /**
   * The admin class is basically the main controller for the backend.
     *
    * @author      PyroCMS Dev Team
    * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012, PyroCMS LLC
    * @package      PyroCMS\Core\Controllers
      */
   class mobile extends REST_Controller
    {
function __contruct()
{   
        parent::__construct();
    }

function content_get()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('default_blog');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $this->response($query->result_array(),200);
}

}
```

IF i dont use pyro cms and use codeigniter normal package + Phil sturgeon REST Client then i can access the above method by going to 
   http://example.com/pyrocms-pyrocms-dc143bc/api/mobile/content.json
but in pyro cms i am not able to access it this way.

**Edit**

I have renamed the content.php to  mobile.php and placed it in 
  pyrocms-pyrocms-dc143bc/system/cms/modules/blog/controllers
I am now able to access this controller with following url :-
  http://example.com/pyrocms-pyrocms-dc143bc/blog/mobile/content

{ 
    status: false,
    error: "Invalid API Key."
   }

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this by editing the config.php 
by setting the

```
 $config['encryption_key']= "to_some_dummy_key"
```